# How can I disable a button from being pressed while I show a graphic for 5 seconds?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I disable a UIButton from being pressed...
 while I show a graphic for 5 seconds?

```
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // if you need the whole view  disabled
    //self.btn.enabled = NO; //if you need button only disabled

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:^ 
        {
            // your graphical changes
            [(UILabel*)addLbl[1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        } 
    completion:^ (BOOL finished) 
        {

            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            //self.button.enabled = YES;
            [(UILabel*)addLbl[1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the delay method:

```
//make your animations and graphical changes..
//....

self.myButton.enabled = NO;
[self performSelector:@selector(changeButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0]; //this will happen after 5 seconds

-(void)changeButton {
self.myButton.enabled = YES; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//EDITED. Try this instead

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // if you need the whole view  disabled

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:^ {
  [(UILabel*)addLbl[1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
} completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^ {
   [(UILabel*)addLbl[1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
 } completion:^ (BOOL hasFinished) {
   self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 }];
}];
```

Comment: after that segment of code, i put up another graphic, however, execution won't show the temporary graphic when I put in the other graphic after that code segment

Comment: If you need to animate few sequences in a line, like first: the door opens; second: a man walks through the door - then try putting your other animations inside the completion block of first animation. Let me know if that sounds clear.

Comment: I did that, and that after the block... the result is that the temporary graphic never shows

Comment: I suppose I'll need your code snippet to help you better. Please share it.

Comment: if I leave out that change back to white, it stays red(temporary graphic)

Comment: The red graphic? Are you 100% sure that this (UILabel*)addLbl[1] is correct label? Have you tried putting it into NSLog? If it shows that it's an allocated UILabel then the code above should work.

Comment: the red graphic will show if I leave out the white graphic set afterwards

Comment: I through a point at you for your help... the other guy's solution worked.. thx